# Add a caption to a WheelView

Tags: android, android-widget, android-view, android-custom-view, android-gui

I'm using the WheelView( http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/ ) to let users input a number of a certain unit (e.g. kg). I'd like to display the unit of the current value next to it like it is shown in this picture.

[image: WheelView with caption "hour"]

Sadly, the WheelView doesn't support labelling (anymore). Any idea how I can implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i know this is **not exactly** what you want, but the closest thing to it, and it can be done easily. you could include your tag in the format string, like this:

`wheelView.setViewAdapter(new NumericWheelAdapter(getActivity(), 0, 23, "%02d hour"))`

Comment: This is not exactly what I was looking for but a usable solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try it:

String[] dayArray = {"2 JAN", "3 jan", "4 jan", "5 jan", "6 jan", "7 jan", "8 jan"};
    WheelView  day;

```
day = (WheelView) findViewById(R.id.day);
        day.setViewAdapter(new DayArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, dayArray, weekDay));


        day.addChangingListener(new OnWheelChangedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onChanged(WheelView wheel, int oldValue, int newValue) {

                Log.e("onChanged hours", dayArray[newValue]);

                mCustomDate = dayArray[newValue];
                mFinalTime = mCustomDate+" "+mCustomHour+mCustomMinute+" "+mAMORPM;
                mSeletedDateTextView.setText(mFinalTime);
            }
        });
```